# issue with submit in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

data.php

```
<?php
$name = strtoupper($_REQUEST['name']);
if(isset($name)){
    $html = "<p>Your name: <b>".$name."</b></p>";
    print($html);
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form form').submit(function(){
            $('#content').load('data.php', { 'name': $('input[name="urname"]').val()});                     
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="form">
<form>
Name : <input type="text" name="urname"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:

For `return false;`, from I know, it will stop the submit action, so I think when I click submit button, it will load the data first, then stop submit action. But after I remove `return false;`, it did not load the data any more, why?

Comment: It probably does load the data, but then the page immediately refreshes. The default action is submitting the form *and* loading the page the form is submitted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the `return false;` the page refreshes because it then submits the form. That is why you cannot see the effect of load function.